# How to change exact occurence of a name in a pandas dataframe cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. In one of the columns, strings are stored. I want to change the name on those string with the new ones:

Here is an example:

```
    old_names = ['Adam', 'Alan', 'Andrew', 'Frank', 'Harry', 'Jack', 
'Josh', 'Justin', 'Roger', 'Ryan', 'Amanda', 'Betsy', 'Courtney', 'Ellen',
 'Heather', 'Katie', 'Kristin', 'Melanie', 'Nancy', 'Stephanie']

    new_names = ['Hanna', 'Brayden', 'Brooklyn', 'Ashlynn', 'Joshua', 
'Britni', 'Latoya', 'Hunter', 'Kaylie', 'Infant', 'Ashlea', 'Haley',
 'Caleb', 'Gage', 'Raheem', 'Mariel', 'Hakeem', 'Lukas', 'Isis', 'Nia']
```

I want to replace old_names[0] with new_names[0] old_names[1] with new_names[1] and so on. To do that, I did the following:

```
def change_names(data,old,new):
    for i in range(len(prev)):
        data['Sentence'] = data['Sentence'].str.replace(old[i],new[i])
    return data

data = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
changed_data = change_names(data,old_names,new_names)
```

If I apply this function I replace `Harry` with `Latoyaua` because it first replace Harry with Joshua and then while replacing Josh with Latoya it also replace the prefix of Joshua with `Latoya`.

How can I fix this problem ?

EDIT

This is a sample row from the dataframe:

```
>>> t.loc[220]
Sentence                            Harry feels angry.
Template        <person subject> feels <emotion word>.
Person                                           Harry
Name: 220, dtype: object
```

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? `old_names = new_names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# create a dictionary of old to new name
map_names = dict(zip(old_names, new_names))

# sample data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence':['Harry feels angry','Adam is happy','Frank went crazy.']})

# map new names to old names
df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map_names.get(y, y) for y in x.split()))

print(df)

    sentence
0   Joshua feels angry
1   Hanna is happy
2   Ashlynn went crazy.
```

Comment: You can also remove `[]`  like `.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map_names.get(y, y) for y in x.split()))` for generator